# Spark SQL - Can not write all records to the hive table

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new in Apache Spark framework and I am using ApacheSpark for writing data to the Hadoop via Hive.

In the code below, I am reading the table_1 from hive and creating dataset, then map to this dataset to another one. After all saving the result dataset to the another table_2.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dataset<Row> ipSet = spark.sql("Select distinct ip from table_1");
    ipSet.map(new TestFunction(), Encoders.bean(MyPojoClass.class)).write().mode("append").insertInto("table_2");
}


// ...
public class TestFunction implements MapFunction<Row, MyPojoClass>
{
 
    private static List<..> staticData;
    private static boolean callOnce = false;

    private static void initStaticData() throws IOException
    {
        staticData = // set the data,
        callOnce = true;
    }


    @Override
    public MyPojoClass call(Row value) throws Exception {
        if (!calledOnce)
            initStaticData();
        String ip = value.getAs("ip");
        return new MyPojoClass(ip);
    }
}
```

The number of the rows in the two different tables should be the same, however number of the rows in result dataset/table_2 are different.

for instance, table_1 has 9.000.000 distinct rows whereas table_2 has 42.000 distinct rows. How can i solve this? (Or i am missing some concept about spark? )

Comment: You are reading whole table_1 with distinct, so you are writing only distinct values in table_2. Also in append mode, so if any previous value already exists in table_2 will be preserved. It seems weird  that they both should have the same number of rows

Comment: @SCouto 9.000.000 is the distinct numbers. Therefore table_2 must have 9.000.000 distinct rows!

Comment: I'm not fluent in Spark with Java, but it seems right to me. Maybe the problem is that the table's metadata is not updated? Try running an MSCK repair table on table_2 after performing the insert and then check it again

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar kind of problem in past.

It was mainly because of the spark SQL row function `getAs`.

[GetAsAPI](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html)
getAs(String fieldName)
Returns the value of a given fieldName. For primitive types, if the value is null it returns 'zero value' specific for primitive ie. 0 for Int.

So there may be the same case with you your IP address may null in most of the cases and other data behaves according to null or 0 value of "ip" in your code.